# Error: incompatible types (for sets)

Tags: java

Is there a such thing as casting Sets?

I have a constructor that takes `Set<String> things` as a parameter, and I would like to set a field `TreeSet<String> stuff` to be this initial set of things. However, I keep getting an error. Java is not liking my statment

```
stuff = things;
```

So I am wondering if putting all elements of things into a list and then moving the elements of that list into stuff is a good solution, or if there is a better way.

Here is what I've come up with:

```
public class Anagrams {
   private TreeSet<String> allWords;  

   //pre: the given dictionary must be in alphabetical order, if null throws an 
   //  illegalArgumentException
   //post: creates a new anagram solver
   public Anagrams(Set<String> dictionary) {
      if(dictionary == null) {
         throw new IllegalArgumentException();
      }
      for(String word : dictionary){
         String temp = word;
         allWords.add(word);
      }     
   }
```

Comment: Can you provide somewhat more code context?  Can we see the declarations of `stuff` and `things`?

Comment: I get an error if I just say `allWords = dictionary`

Answer (score 2):

Instantiate a new `TreeSet<String>` by populating it from `things`:

```
stuff = new TreeSet<String>(things);
```

Answer (score 0):

it is because `TreeSet` is a child of `Set` so you cannot asign a set to a tree set (the other way is possible)

so you'd need to cast explicitly (provided `things` is a `TreeSet<String>`:

```
stuff = (TreeSet<String>) things;
```